# Cron job creating files each time it runs

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that runs the script every 30 minutes. The problem is each time it runs the cron it creates a file in the root directory. It'll create files like this:

```
wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron.1
wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron.2
wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron.3
```

This is my cron:

```
*/30 * * * * wget http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

How can I make it auto delete after it finishes running the cron job or make it not create the file?

Answer (score 0):

wget primarily is for downloading files, it might be better to use `curl`

`curl http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`